# "pyinstaller: error: no such option: --add-data" while converting py to exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller==3 on both Linux and windows, and I'm trying to embed a docx file with a py file while converting it into an exe file, but it gives me that error (in the title),

Moreover, this is the command I use to convert on Linux:

```
wine /root/.wine/drive_c/python27/scripts/pyinstaller.exe --add-data "/root/download/MEDAAPPLICATIONFORM.docx;." --onefile --noconsole zx.py
```

Same error occurrs when I try it on widnows.

Comment: Try putting `--add-data "/root/download/MEDAAPPLICATIONFORM.docx;."` right before `zx.py`.

Comment: @Xnero thank you for replying but it didn't work

Comment: Does it work without `--add-data`?

Comment: Note: If you are using Linux, the path separator is a colon, so it would be: `--add-data "/root/download/MEDAAPPLICATIONFORM.docx:."`

Comment: Its actually a semicolon, I'm not sure if colon is okay to be used, but yet it didn't work with the colon

Comment: If you use a Linux-based system, you use a colon.

Comment: Did it work when you used a colon?

Comment: No sir, it didnt.

Comment: Does it work without `--add-data`?

Comment: yes it works without it, but I need to use it

Comment: Sounds like you’re using an old version of pyinstaller. Try `pip install -U pyinstaller` to update. You might need a newer version of Python.

Comment: @Balmy I'm using the latest version now which is 4.5.1, I also tried other versions too